# Regex to split an array in Ruby based on Pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, split

This is more of a "What regex do I use" rather than a semantics question.

I have the following string :

```
moneyString = "¥10,100 YEN,€100.00 EU,$100.00 US"
```

And I need to split it on the comma. However, I don't want the comma in the `10,000` Yen to be separated into two arrays.

Currently, if I do `moneyString.split(',')`

I get : `[¥10, 100 YEN, €100.00 EU, $100.00 US]` as the different array values. But I want :

`[¥10100 YEN, €100.00 EU, $100.00 US]`

Can someone show me how to get this regex correct? I'm sorry, but I am a complete newbie with this stuff.

Comment: Where does YEN come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split on all commas that are NOT preceded by a number, using negative lookbehind.

```
moneyString = "¥10,100 YEN,€100.00 EU,$100.00 US"

puts moneyString.split(/(?<!\d),/)

# ¥10,100 YEN
# €100.00 EU
# $100.00 US
```

Answer (score 1):

```
moneyString.split(/(?<!\d),/)
```

The keyword is "negative look-behind".